# Pivoting an empty dataframe produces a columns MULTIindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I'm running into an issue where `pivot_table` is producing a MultiIndex instead of an Index for the columns when I apply it to an empty dataframe.

So here's what I'm trying to do.  I've got some data that I'm reading into a dataframe `df`.  One column of this dataframe is `'type'` and what I need is to split the dataframe `df` into two dataframes `df2` and `df3` based on the type in that column of `df`.  While most of the time the data I pass in to create `df` will have both types (types `'A'` and `'B'` below), sometimes I may be missing values of one type of the other.

However, I need to create a pivot table from each with missing columns and indices added, filled with 0s where necessary.  This is fine when the type isn't missing from the data: I can just use `.reindex` twice to fill in the missing indices and columns.  But if the type is totally missing, then one of the derived dataframes (`df2` or `df3` below) will be empty.  In that case, the index ends up being a multiindex.

Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A', 'A', 'A'], 'val': [1, 2, 3], 'col': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'ind': [6, 6, 8]})
df2 = df[df['type'] == 'A'][['val', 'col', 'ind']].pivot_table(values='val', index='ind', columns='col', fill_value=0)
df3 = df[df['type'] == 'B'][['val', 'col', 'ind']].pivot_table(values='val', index='ind', columns='col', fill_value=0)
```

What I'd like to do at this point is chain `.reindex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], axis=1, fill_value=0).reindex(list(range(6, 9)), axis=0, fill_value=0)` onto `df2` and `df3`.  But that produces an error because `df3`'s column index is `MultiIndex([], names=[None, 'col'])` instead of `Index([], name='col')` as I would expect.  And further I cannot just drop None seemingly because things like `.drop(columns=None)` just clearly wouldn't/ doesn't work.

Is there an efficient and simple way to handle this?

---

To distill the problem down a bit in case what I should really be doing is refactoring the whole thing, I have data that will look something like this

```
{'type': ['A', 'A', 'A'], 'val': [1, 2, 3], 'col': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'ind': [6, 6, 8]}
```

The `type` list may or may not include both types `'A'` and `'B'`.

From this I need to create two separate dataframes to capture the information separately for types `'A'` and `'B'` that is robust enough to handle when either is missing.  The resultant dataframes should look like this with the above example.

```
df2 = 
    'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
6    1   2   0   0
7    0   0   0   0
8    3   0   0   0

and

df3 =
    'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
6    0   0   0   0
7    0   0   0   0
8    0   0   0   0
```

Comment: I guess you could create a empty df with the desired columns and index (like this - `pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index=[6, 7, 8])` )   and merge this with your `df2` and `df3` and `.fillna(0)` after merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. There may be a better efficient way to do this, but this works for your data set. One thing I am not able to get right is to keep only the matching column values after the merge, but I have managed it in a different way (hope that is not right)

All I did here is create a empty df with the desired columns and index and merge this with your `df2` and `df3` and `.fillna(0)` after merge.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A', 'A', 'A'], 'val': [1, 2, 3], 'col': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'ind': [6, 6, 8]})

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index=[6, 7, 8])

    df2 = df1.merge(df[df['type'] == 'A'][['val', 'col', 'ind']].pivot_table(values='val', index='ind', columns='col', fill_value=0),
                    left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left', suffixes=('','_y')).fillna(0.0)

    df3 = df1.merge(df[df['type'] == 'B'][['val', 'col', 'ind']].pivot_table(values='val', index='ind', columns='col', fill_value=0),
                    left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left').fillna(0.0)

# this section need rework as I mentioned above
    df2['a'], df2['b'] = df2['a_y'], df2['b_y']
    df2 = df2.drop(['a_y', 'b_y'],1)

    print(df2)
    print(df3)
```

Output:

df2:

```
     a    b    c    d
6  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

df3:

```
     a    b    c    d
6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```